# Adding Admin Menu Separators in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to create an admin menu separator that allows you to put them in with code. This is the function:

```php
function add_admin_menu_separator($position) {
  global $menu;
  $index = 0;
  foreach($menu as $offset => $section) {
    if (substr($section[2],0,9)=='separator')
    $index++;
    if ($offset>=$position) {
      $menu[$position] = array('','read',"separator{$index}",'','wp-menu-separator');
      break;
    }
  }
  ksort( $menu );
}
```

The add action bit is below

```php
add_action('admin_init','admin_menu_separator');
    
function admin_menu_separator() {
  add_admin_menu_separator(220);
}
```

It works okay but it produces the following errors in WordPress when rearranging menus:

```
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/user/public_html/wp-creation.com/wp-content/themes/liquid_theme_0.4_licensed/functions.php on line 174
    
> Warning: ksort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/user/public_html/wp-creation.com/wp-content/themes/liquid_theme_0.4_licensed/functions.php on line 182
```

Comment: I'm guessing you haven't applied an array, hence why `ksort()` is reporting that a `null` has been given.. Since no array has been processed by the foreach loop, it will generate the warning

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should hook in `admin_menu`:

```
add_action('admin_menu','admin_menu_separator');
```

And use something lower than `220`. The biggest `offset` I got in my system is `99`.

Check [this very fine class](https://gist.github.com/mikeschinkel/792b7aa5b695d1092520) to deal with Admin Menus.
It appeared in this WPSE Question: [Add a Separator to the Admin Menu?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2666/add-a-separator-to-the-admin-menu)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add this in functions.php

```
add_action('admin_menu', function () {   
  global $menu;
  $menu[49] = ['', 'read', '', '', 'wp-menu-separator'];
});
```

Where 49 is separator position, You have to remember that separator position can replace your menu element if it has the same position.